# Validation/disabling dates of Calendar Column in Datagridview control

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, .net-3.5

Can you please advice on disabling the dates in the Calendar column in datagridview control.Below is the requirement

> ```
> -> User is not allowed to select a date which is less than today's date and the next 1 month
> dates.
>
> Example -
> Today's Date -  **Sep 12th 2014** 
> Now all the dates less than Sep12th,2014 are disabled and the dates till **Oct12,2014**
> i.e till next month are disabled.
> So user is allowed to select the dates only after Oct12th,2014.
>
> --> When the calendar column is added to the Datagrid..it must already show the dates from next month.As per above example from
> ```
>
> Oct13th,2014.

Can you pls advice on how can i achieve this.

Thanks,
Prathap

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will get you started. I setup a datagridview with one column called "Date" that lists a different date in each row. To figure out which dates to make readonly I use the following code:

```
Dim myDate As Date = Date.Today
Dim rowNumber As Integer = 0
Dim rowDate As Date = Nothing
Dim enabledDate As Date = myDate.AddDays(30)

Do Until rowDate = enabledDate
    rowDate = DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).Value

    If rowDate < enabledDate Then
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).ReadOnly = True
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.Gray
    Else
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).ReadOnly = False
        DataGridView1.Rows(rowNumber).Cells(0).Style.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If

    rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
Loop
```

The way this is set up though you'll need to populate 'enabledDate' with a different value based on what month it is. For this month you would add 30 days, but next month it would need to be 31.

Hope this helps.

Comment: VB code it is which i dont understand in detail..but i got the idea.Will startoff with this.Thanks.